# WebComponents - detect parent overflow and its size

Tags: javascript, web-component, native-web-component

I'm working on a native WebComponent that represents a simple table, the number of row and columns are coming via attributes. The width of columns if fixed.

In case that I have 20 columns and column width = 150px, I need to create only as many columns as I can fit in the parent container without creating a y-overflow.

here is how I create the table

```
...
this._root = this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
...


_createTable() {
      const parentWidth = this.getRootNode(); // how to get the width of parent container
      console.log(222, parentWidth)

      this._cells = [];
      this._table = document.createElement('table');
      for (let row = 0; row < this._rows; row++) {
        const tr = document.createElement('tr');
        this._table.appendChild(tr);
        this._cells.push([]);
        let totalWidth = 0;
        for (let col = 0; col < this._cols; col++) {
          // can we create a new cell/column
          if (totalWidth + this._columnWidth > parentWidth)
            break;
          totalWidth += this._columnWidth;
          const td = document.createElement('td');
          td.innerText = `cell[${row}${col}]`;
          tr.appendChild(td);
          this._cells[row].push(td);
        }
      }

      this._root.appendChild(this._table);
    }
```

but I could not find a way how from my `web-component` to get the parent width and attach to its resize event.

Because the web-component is inside a shadow-dom, I cannot really access the parent, maybe I'm wrong here, but `parentNode` always returns null.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

ShadowRoot is a DocumentFragment, so they will always have `parentNode` set to `null`, but they do have a `host` property pointing to the element they are attached to.

Comment: from any element inside shadowDOM its: ``.getrootNode().host``